# Outlook VBA code to run after reading an unread email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I would like to create a macro that every time I close an email asks me if I want to move it to a folder.

I wrote something like this:

```vbs
Private Sub Application_ItemClose(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' Check if the item is a mail item
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        ' Check if the mail item was unread
        If Item.UnRead = True Then
            ' Prompt the user to select a folder to move the email item to
            Dim moveFolder As Outlook.Folder
            Set moveFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder

            ' Check if a folder was selected
            If Not moveFolder Is Nothing Then
                ' Move the email item to the selected folder
                Item.Move moveFolder
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

However `ItemClose` is not a valid Outlook event. I tried other events, but couldn't find one that runs when I close an email window.
Also, I'm not sure if `Item.UnRead = True` will work in this scenario (i.e. if the mail becomes UnRead as soon as I open it and will never be unread when I close the window). But unfortunately I could not reach that point to check this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is no `Application.ItemClose` event. There is `MailItem.Close` event (also available for other items, such as `ContactItem` etc.), and it fires when an inspector is closed. But if you read an item in the preview (reading) pane, it won't fire.

If you only want to track an event when an inspector is closed, use `Inspector.Close` event (keep in mind that there can be more than one open inspector). You can hook up inspector events if you track `Inspectors.NewInspector` event (where `Inspectors` collection comes from `Application.Inspectors`).

If you want to handle preview pane events, hook up `MailItem.PropertyChange` event (and watch for the `"UnRead"` event parameter) for the unread items. You can do so by hooking up `Explorer.SelectionChange` event and hooking the events of the items from the `Explorer.Selection` collection (unhook the previously tracked items before handing the new selection). Again, keep in mind that there can be multiple selected items and multiple `Explorer` objects (`Application.Explorers` collection and `Explorers.NewExplorer` event). Not exactly fun to handle multiple object events in VBA...

If you want to see the events a particular OOM object exposes, you can use [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select an item you are interested in, click Item button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the events tab. OutlookSpy will log the events and their parameters as Outlook raises them.

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in the [PropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.propertychange) event which is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, `UnRead`) of the object is changed. The property name is passed to the event so that you can determine which property was changed.

Also you may find the [MailItem.Unload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.unload) event helpful. It is fired before an Outlook item is unloaded from memory, either programmatically or by user action. This event occurs after the [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.close(even)) event for the Outlook item occurs, but before the Outlook item is unloaded from memory, allowing an add-in to release any resources related to the object. Although the event occurs before the Outlook item is unloaded from memory, this event *cannot be canceled*.

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 
Public Sub Initialize_Handler() 
 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub myItem_Close(Cancel As Boolean) 
 If Not myItem.Saved Then 
   myItem.Save 
   MsgBox " The item was saved." 
 End If 
End Sub
```

There are also UI-related events like [Inspector.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.close(even)) or [Explorer.SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selectionchange) that also can be helpful in your scenario.